# Export non-csv format data, parameters "delimiter" and "with_header" are meanless in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

When I use `copy-into` syntax to load data from `json` file into cnosdb, I found I can provide `delimiter` and `with_header` parameters. I think these two parameters should only be used in importing `csv` file and meanless in other file format. Am I right?

```
public ❯ copy into 'test' from air file_format = (type = 'json', delimiter = '@', with_header = true);
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 6    |
+------+
Query took 0.007 seconds.
```